# Usage of bodyParser.text() in Express with EJS

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, body-parser

I am building a search engine app with Express that queries the Twitter API v1.1. Currently, I am trying to submit the search string to my server by parsing form data with the bodyParser module.  Here is the code:

index.ejs

```
...
<form method="GET" action="/results">
    <input id="input" type="text" name="search">
    <button id="searchButton">+</button>
</form>
...
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public");

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/results', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.render('results')
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Our app is running on http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

The code shown will return *{ }* to the console.  If I try and access req.body.search it returns *undefined* (obviously).  What is the issue here?  Why is it not logging my search string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong body decoder. If you're submitting a form (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the default `enctype` for forms), you will need `bodyParser.urlencoded()` instead of `bodyParser.text()`. The latter is for plaintext request data, not form data.

Additionally, you should also be using `method="POST"` and a `POST` route (`app.post('/results', ...)`) instead of `method="GET"` and a `GET` route. Since `GET` requests almost never have a body, the browser instead transforms the form data into a querystring that is then appended to the url itself. This means your form data is currently in `req.query` instead of `req.body`. Switching to `POST` though will cause the browser to send the form data in the request body, and the form data will be in `req.body` as expected.

Comment: Didn't make a difference.  Even switched to `enctype="text/plain"` and kept the _js_ file the same.

Comment: You don't want `text/plain` for forms. I've updated my answer to explain the additional issue at play here.

Comment: So that solved that issue.  Now, when I run the server with `heroku local web` it appends a "?" at the end and 301's, but if I use `node server.js` it runs smoothly.  Any thoughts on that? Note: my _Procfile_ says `web: node server.js`.

Comment: Thanks! Pushed it to Heroku and no issues.. debugging with `node` I guess.